# How to handle arbitrary user supplied types in my library?

Tags: java, generics, shared-libraries

I'm writing a library which is able to handle hexagon grids.

The user has access to a `HexagonGridBuilder` object where he can set the width, height and a lot of other parameters for the grid and its `build()` method returns a `HexagonGrid` object. The `HexagonGrid` has various methods to get a `Hexagon` (for example by grid coordinate, or pixel coordinate).

My problem is that I want to allow the user to put arbitrary satellite data in each `Hexagon` object on the `HexagonGrid`. What is the best practice to do so?

I can provide generic methods to allow the user to pass satellite data to a `Hexagon`:

```
private Object satelliteData;

public <T> void setSatelliteData(T satelliteData) {
    this.satelliteData = satelliteData;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T getSatelliteData() {
    return (T) satelliteData;
}
```

This is obviously flawed since it involves casting objects without being sure what their type is.

I can modify my `HexagonGridBuilder` so the user can pass a `Class` object for his satellite data so I can validate whether he supplied the right type or not:

```
   public <T> void setSatelliteData(T satelliteData) {
    if (!satelliteClass.isAssignableFrom(satelliteData.getClass())) {
        // throw some exception
    }
    this.satelliteData = satelliteData;
}
```

But this will still involve unchecked casts in the `getSatelliteData()` method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T getSatelliteData() {
    return (T) satelliteData;
}'
```

The right soulution seems making the whole library generic so I have a generic parameter for the satellite data type but it involves making every class involved generic:

```
HexagonGrid<SATELLITE_DATA_TYPE> hexagonGrid =
new HexagonGridBuilder<SATELLITE_DATA_TYPE>().build();
```

So I'm not sure which one to choose. Which is the least hacky solution? Or is there something else I did not think about?

***edit:** What I really wish to know is that is it worth the trouble to make all of my involved classes generic (which will make them harder to understand and a bit messy) or I can get away with the 2 generic methods and a plus method in my builder to supply the class? The reason is that it is possible that the user won't use any satellite data so it will be fuss and feathers.*

Comment: I agree with chrylis's answer, but for future reference it isn't absolutely forbidden to make unchecked casts - in general you want to avoid unchecked casts since they may throw an exception, but in this case you're first verifying that the cast is legal and so there's no risk of having an exception thrown

Comment: There's a reason the warning is suppressible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place `<T>` as a type parameter on your entire `HexagonGrid` class, not just on the methods. Then you can define your field as `private T satelliteData`, eliminate the `<T>`s on the methods, and remove the explicit cast. This is basically the approach you talked about last.

If there's a reason you want to use a builder rather than a constructor, you don't necessarily have to genericize the builder; you could pass in the type parameter to the `build` method. See [EnumSet#noneOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) for an example of how this would look.

(Also, given the rest of your requirements, you may want to look at making your type parameter `<T extends Satellite>`, or whatever your base satellite interface is.)

Comment: The satellite data is entirely arbitrary. It is for the user to add data to a `Hexagon` (like is it selected or not). I don't care what data he adds so I don't need a `Satellite` interface.

Comment: In that case, you're fine with <T>.